# Query in batch?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

Using gcloud-node is it possible to query in batches (multiple queries in 1 network call)? I know it is possible to get and delete in batches, but can I do the same with queries somehow?

Comment: As a note, including more information on why you need this and what your trying to do with it increases the chances it gets picked up as a feature request

Answer (score 2):

No, Cloud Datastore doesn't support query batches, so none of the client libraries can do this.

The alternative it to send queries in parallel instead.